# Choosing the values for this magnetostriction oscillator circuit

Tags: circuit-analysis, sensor, integrated-circuit, bjt, oscillator

I'm working with the following magnetostriction oscillator, and I need helping to set the values for L1, C1, L2, and V (my BJT is a 2N2222) such that the length of my iron rod (labeled as ferromagnetic rod) is less than equal to 25 cm and its diameter is in a range of 3 to 6 mm.

[image]

If *l* is the length of the iron rod then-->
[image]

Where Y is the Young's modulus (208 x 10^9 PA from what I know) and P is the density (7860 kg/m^3)

The permeability is 6.3 *10^-3 and ideally, I'd like the magnetic field B1 created by L1 to be equal to 0.63 tesla (so that I can use a 0.1 mm thick copper wire for it.)

I'm not sure how to do the beta and alpha calculations to set the voltage and find out the collector and emitter currents, and I'm also not sure how to do the calculations for the current/voltage induced in L2.

Could someone please share a schematic for how the transistor becomes a current source when there is an EMF induced in L2? I can’t seem to understand that properly.

Comment: what is your specific question?

Comment: I need to find values of V, L1, L2 and C so as to ensure that the length l of the iron core is less than 25 cm

Comment: that is not a question .... what is preventing you from determining the component values?

Comment: I don't know how to do these calculations because I'm not very familiar with BJTs and the common emitter amplifier orientation where there is an increase in collector current

Comment: **1** Do you have a specific requirement for the frequency of oscillation ? Why do you say "*length .. less than 25 cm*" ? Why is the length (and dia) more important than the frequency of oscillation ? **2** Are you actually building this circuit ? or just simulating it ? **3** If you are only simulating this circuit, do you already have a mathematical model of the rod vibrations ? **4** What is the need for `0.63 T` ? **5** Where did you find this circuit ? Please provide a link if you have one.

Comment: 1. Ideally I want a frequency between 10 and 20khZ. Length and diameter specifications are important because I'm working with this oscillator for a school project (extended essay), and will be working on analyzing the effect of rod temperature on frequency and amplitude of actual oscillations - and will have to heat the rod in a lab (hence size may affect whether it heats evenly)
2) yes I'm actually Building this circuit
3) I have the mathematical formulas for the nature of vibrations (independent of temperature) - but I don't understand the oscillation in a dc circuit and the Hfe

Comment: 3) continued - as all the youtube videos I seem to have covered don't explain the common-emitter current amplification for the collector

4) The need for the 0.63 T is because the perm of iron is 6.3 * 10^-3 and allows me to use copper coils of 0.5mm (for the solenoid formula)
5) Some youtube links (I don't think these YouTubers explain the circuit well):
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K4Do_yWJt2k&ab_channel=PHYSICSFORMEDICALANDENGINEERING
https://www.ques10.com/p/31391/explain-the-principle-construction-and-working-of-/
https://kanchiuniv.ac.in/coursematerials/UNIT-4-Ultrasonics.pdf

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: No its a research project that I'm undertaking out of my own free will

Comment: Your osc will not start .There is no bias .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First look at the equation. You have Y,P and a desired range (upper bound) of length (l not L). It's trivial to convert that into a range of available frequencies with a lower bound, so do that first, and choose an achievable frequency ( >= that lower bound).

If that is achievable (the lower bound encompasses the frequency range you want) you can compute an LC product from the LHS of the formula, and choose C such that L1 is in the microhenry to millihenry range for reasonable windings.

So far you haven't had to know anything about transistors.

But now you have to learn about common emitter stages and biasing networks, to turn that over-simplified sketch into a practical design. (Without base bias, there is no way for it to start!) That's a bit too big to tackle in a question; I recommend a book like Horowitz&Hill or a college course in analog electronics.

(If the frequencies are really in the sub-MHz range you may find an opamp easier to work with)

Comment: Thank you so much! I'll be sure to check out the book and look into analog electronics. I have dabbled in transistors a bit, but all of them were MOSFETS, so I haven't experienced current gain Transistors before. Thanks a lot once again!!